# He has not enough reputation to comment and made a new question, how to proceed?

Tags: discussion, comment, privileges, new-users

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911868/a-question-about-an-answer) asks for an clarification of an answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903881/characterisation-of-one-dimensional-sobolev-space). Do I post an answer to his new question, or do I post a comment in my answer and flag his new question?

Remark: He did it, because he has not enough reputation to make a comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Questions of the form "how does equation (x) follow?" [referring to some mathematical text] are asked frequently, and make reasonably good questions on their own. The fact that the text under consideration is placed on this site makes some difference but not a lot. I would do the following:

1. Post an answer to the question, as I would to other "clarify a proof" questions.
2. Go back to the answer and either (a) leave a comment pointing to clarification, or (b) edit the answer.

The choice  between (a) and (b) depends on the mathematical substance. If you think the proof is actually well written and the asker was confused due to insufficient background for reading the proof, a comment is enough. If you think you were sloppy/hasty when writing the answer, then edit it.

Comment: I don't know what happened to me, but somehow I was thinking that the new question was made by the same author of the previous question (you can infer this by my question here). Now I saw that, in fact, it was made by another person. I have answered the question now.

Comment: @Tomás FYI, question asker can always comment on answers to their question, regardless of reputation.

Comment: Yes, I should have infered this too =). Anyway, what is FYI?

Comment: @Tomás A common abbreviation of "for your information".

Comment: Any idea for a better title for the question?

Comment: @Tomás I edited the title and the question itself.